# Xcm V2Traits Error UntrustedTeleportLocation

Tags: polkadot, parachain, xcm, relay-chain

When I'm sending assets from relay chain to a parachain by using Limited Teleport assets. I`m facing this issue [image]

Answer (score 2):

DOT can't be teleported from the relay chain because it can't be dependent on the governance of a parachain (statemint is an exception because it has the relay chain's governance).

Rather than doing this you can reserve transfer the funds to your parachain's account on the relay chain (or statemint) and then when the parachain receives the callback XCM message it can mint a token on the parachain that represents this DOT (parachainlocalDOT) and send that to the user's account. It would be the parachain's responsibility to account for the parachainlocalDOT token and it could redeem that token for DOT on the relay chain (or statemint at a later point).